# How do I use permutation to find all possible words from an input?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I am doing a project for my programming class, here are the 5 things that I am working towards. Thanks for your help!

1. list of valid words will be provided in a words.txt
2. ask for input that only accepts a combination of 2-8 letters
3. Ex. input would be "polo"
4. Find all possible valid words of this input from inside words.txt
5. Possible outcomes, "poo" "pool" "loop" "polo"

   ```
   import random
   import itertools

   file_name='words.txt'
   DEBUG=True

   def load_words():
       try:
           f=open(file_name,'r')
           str1=f.read()
           f.close()
       except:
           print('Problem opening the file',file_name)
       list1=[]
       list1=str1.split()
       if DEBUG:
           length=len(list1)
           print('Number of words is',length)
           print(list1[0],list1[length//2],list1[-1])
           for i in range(10):
               print(list1[random.randint(1,length)])
       return(list1)

   def is_valid(str1,list1):
       valid=False
       count=0
       if str1 in list1:
           valid=True
       return valid

   def generate(letters):
       print(len(letters))
       count=1
       answers=[]
       for length in range(2,len(letters)+1):
           for x in itertools.permutations(letters,length):
               word=''
               for let in x:
                   word+=let
               print(word)
               if is_valid(word):
                   answers.append(word)
               count+=1   
           print(count,x)
           return(answers)

   def main():
       words=load_words()
       generate('abcde')
       guess=input('Check a word')
       if is_valid(guess.upper(),words):
           print(guess,'is a real word')
       else:
           print(guess,'is not a real word')

   main()
   ```

Comment: What is the actual question you would like help answering? Simply posting your project and it's goals isn't a concrete question.

Comment: Right now I am getting an error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not module" I cant figure out where this is happening at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as the error is concerned 
print(list1[random].randint(1,length)) should be changed to
print(list1[random.randint(1,length)])

Comment: Thank you, that has gotten me past that error, now I run into "is_valid() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" I guess it is under my def generate(), but I dont know what to put inside of the argument besides word.

Comment: you are welcome :)...you put the corresponding list that the function is_valid expects..